# File Size Limits with MBtiles

Tags: gdal, mbtiles

I'm running into an issue where my MBtiles files are exceeding the max file size for the file system when created with gdal. Is there a known method of creating a set of mbtiles files that don't exceed a set file size? or will I need to create something?

Comment: What file system? FAT32? FAT32 has a limit of 4GiB but NTFS has a theoretical limit of 16 EiB.. I doubt your files are multi exbibyte in size.

Comment: I suggest to make some tests for finding how large area fits safely into your size limit. Run gdal_translate as many times as you need then with appropriate -projwin https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html for cutting.